# Does ioncube keep comments after original file has been encrypted?

Tags: php, reflection, ioncube

I would like to use the `getDocComment()` function of Reflection to collect the comments above functions. It works well with unencrypted php files. But in the future I would like to encrypt the php sources with Ioncube and I'm wondering whether Ioncube removes internal php comments or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that ioncube leaves intact those comments by default, according to their documentation:

> 3.15.3 Omitting Documentation Comments [
>   --no-doc-comments ] Documentation comments are comments with the following syntax: /** My code comment
>   */ These comments are exposed by the PHP 5 reflection API, and are preserved by the PHP 5 Encoder by default. In order to omit these
>   documentation comments from encoded files specify the
>   --no-doc-comments option.